# MsSql database connectivity error with netbeans IDE 8.1

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

This is my connection class

```
package gov.in.uid; 

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;    
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import gov.in.uid.AuthResponseDetails;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.*;

public class Con_Savelog {
    String Block, Remark;
    public void ins( String Block, String Remark){

        this.Block=Block;
        this.Remark=Remark;
        {
            try
            { 
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AU_UID [sa on Default  
                     schema];user=sa;password=dbadmin;");
                System.out.println("Database Name: " +con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
                PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("insert into UID_Log values (?, ?");
                prep.setString(2, Block);
                prep.setString(3, Remark);
                prep.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Data Inserted");

                ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery("SELECT * from UID_Log");
                String a="";
                String b="";

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    a=rs.getString(2);
                    a=rs.getString(3);
                    System.out.println("Block: " + a+"\r\n"  + " Remark: "+ b);
                }

                con.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("Problem Connecting! "+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running my project I am getting following error:

```
"Problem Connecting! java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0."
```

Comment: Which part of *"Use `sqljdbc4.jar`"* don't you understand?

Comment: exception message is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is to remove sqljdbc.jar from the class and build path(remove this from library portion) and only use sqljdbc4.jar (which is for Java 6 and higher).

Answer (score 0):

Use tomcat 8 and remove that jar. U must use Java1.8 version